# How to QNetworkAccessManager Ftp Delete?

Tags: qt, ftp, qnetworkaccessmanager

I can upload files to ftp. But how do I delete files

Qt Version: 5.2.0

> How to do deleteFile function.

I can upload files to ftp. But how do I delete file
just delete any file on the ftp I would like to, please help. Qnetworkaccessmanag will be using.

no Qftp.

```
    class Uploader: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Uploader(QObject *p = 0): QObject(p)     {  }

    void fileupload(const QString &file)  //OK NO PROBLEM
    {
        QFileInfo finfo(file);
        QUrl url("ftp://www.website.com/"+finfo.fileName());
        url.setUserName("username");
        url.setPassword("pass");

        data = new QFile(file, this);
        if (data->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            reply = nam.put(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
            connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));
            connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), SLOT(uploadDone()));
        }
        else
            qDebug() << "Oops";
    }

    void deletefile(QUrl ftpUrl)       ????????????
   {
       HOW CODE  ????????
   }


public slots:
    void uploadProgress(qint64 bytesSent, qint64 bytesTotal)    {
        qDebug() << "Uploaded" << bytesSent << "of" << bytesTotal;
    }

    void uploadDone()     {
        qDebug() << "Finished" << reply->error();
        data->deleteLater();
        reply->deleteLater();
    }

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
    QFile *data;
    QNetworkReply *reply;
};
```

Comment: Can you show you codes please ?